# jsonp Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, angular4, jsonp

возникает ошибка которую я не знаю как решить [image: ссылка на фото ошибки]

вот код

```
let obs = this.http.jsonp(this.url, 'callback');

obs.subscribe(value => console.log(value), err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Скорее всего ваш JSON невалиден

Comment: а как получить не json, а просто текст

Comment: что за ошибка то?